# TypeScript does not validate generic type of value returned from promise?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'd like to use an async helper function in my TypeScript code that returns a database query builder instantiated for a specific database model type. However, I noticed that TypeScript does not check the specified generics type and so I am able to assign the return value to a variable where the generic type is wrong.

As a simplified example this is valid:

```
class Foobar<T> { }

const asyncFunc = async (): Promise<Foobar<string>> => {
    ...
}    
const caller = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const result: Foobar<number> = await asyncFunc();    
}
```

The type of Foobar is string in the return type of asyncFunc and it is number in the type of the variable "result".

Is this expected behaviour and is there a reason behind this? Is there a way around this?

This is quite annoying for my database code as TypeScript does not now check what I'm trying to insert with my query builder.

Comment: You need to show us your definition of Foobar, because without it it works.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAnmYAxArimBeeSsAUAlAFwwAKATiALYCWEApgDzSV1gDmAfDrwN4BYAFAwYlRlHSUwMAOQAzECDkBuEQF8RI0JFjA4AG0ONKOPMmAxiZKrQYsAbiDoATXtgEixu6OMYQ6IZQZGDoNABGpuZwAO5wdLAIlhgoxKpiYppAA

Comment: @AntonPodolsky Using primitive types like string or number as the type of the promise works and TypeScript complains of the type mismatch, but using a generic class Foobar<T> where T is different on the return value and on the variable that is being assigned to is allowed by TS. Example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28BGYBOAeAKgPmgbwFgAoYgX2OOHgDsIAXaSAT2uFgFdXoBeRiF4NAAUASgBc0AAqp4AWwCWEAKboEyNOnqp51AObZc3XISLRoqJXXapqUmQuUA6CxHggAbkqHUlAdziIKBhaOvqiIgDcZBREVLQMwGAgIEqoPHwCwuJ2cooq7vDyACaGxsRmcfTmShDsIHQSakHo1OyySKmGjL5g8gzMrBysohFmZmRAA

Comment: It's working if `Foobar<T>` actually uses the `T` parameter: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28BGYBOAeAKgPmgbwFgAoaaVAUwgFcQAXALmk2IF9jjh4A7CW6SAJ5dgsKsOgBefhCHBoACgCUjAAqp4AWwCWEcugTI06Xqi1cA5tlwTchEmXK0qqLtDWad5AHQUI8EABu5PJc5ADucIgoGCZmlkqKANys7EScPHzAYCAg5KiS0rIKym7q2rroAfBaACbWtsSk6bwO1HSMBtHoXFQaSHnW-GFgWnyCwqLCSomkpKxAA)

Comment: Yeah, you need to actually use the generic type in your class.

Comment: Unused type parameters are almost never desirable; your class is equivalent to the empty object type `{}` and thus `Foobar<X>` and `Foobar<Y>` are the same type no matter what `X` and `Y` are.  See [the relevant FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that is correct. Coming from Java background I forgot that TypeScript does duck typing. So it's not what type you say something is its the actual structure that matters. So since Foobar is empty it matches other types. But if you use T in Foobar for something then Foobar<string> is no logner assignable to Foobar<number>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is (largely) [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system); two types with the same *shape* or *structure* are considered the same type, even if they have different *names* or *declarations*. Since the following [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) class declaration

```
class Foobar<T> { }
```

does not use the type parameter `T` anywhere structurally inside the class body, then `Foobar<T>` is structurally *independent* of `T`. So the types `Foobar<string>` and `Foobar<number>` are the *same*.  Indeed the class body is (at least in your example) completely empty, and thus `Foobar<T>` is equivalent to the empty [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) `{}` no matter what `T` is.

Empty classes and unused type parameters often lead to surprising results for those used to nominal type systems (such as Java's) and are therefore best avoided.  See the TypeScript FAQ entries [Why do these empty classes behave strangely?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and [Why is `A<string>` assignable to `A<number>` for `interface A<T> {}`?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) for more information.

Assuming you wanted `Foobar<T>` to depend on `T`, you can achieve this by adding some property or method to `Foobar<T>` that actually depends on `T`.  For example:

```
class Foobar<T> {
  prop: T;
  constructor(prop: T) {
    this.prop = prop;
  }
}

declare const asyncFunc: () => Promise<Foobar<string>>;

const caller = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const error: Foobar<number> = await asyncFunc();
  // Type 'Foobar<string>' is not assignable to type 'Foobar<number>'.
  const okay: Foobar<string | number> = await asyncFunc(); // okay
}
```

Now `Foobar<string>` is not assignable to `Foobar<number>`, because the `prop` property `string` is not assignable to `number`.  Note that object types are *covariant* in their property types (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)) so that means `Foobar<string>` is still assignable to `Foobar<string | number>`, because `string` is assignable to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | number`.  If this is undesirable, you might need to modify the way `Foobar<T>` depends on `T`.  But we're getting out of scope for the question as asked, so I'll stop there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28BGYBOAeAKgPmgbwFgAoaaAB1XjIC5pMBuY04eAOwgBdUBXYD+VAAoKVWpgCU+JqWgcAFgEsIAOhFloAXnKUyjEtAC+xI0WIATAKag0F6C3YdokAJ6tgsbm9qDJG3AAVKAFslC3QEZDR0TlQFVgBzbGw9YntOOzAQEAtUTScIV2BoH1pA+BCIMIA3eAUzXD8pfTTHHMpUWgiUDFZuIKQchqcAdzAFRxc3DzcfPVIAenm6ZzJbAHIuqJi4xLXoJWhWeAmoBXjWMCRs2XhZFfXNnr6B1Gw15WkW6HgAazBnTqIbrRLg7aAAH0Oz0GeTAo3G+UK02As2gi2+f2cxiAA)

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer! So yeah looks like because of my Java background I forgot about the differents ways typing may occur. So this is basically duck typing I guess.